# Improve performance of MERGE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a process to calculate the daily sales forecast into a big table in SQL Server 2008 R2 (let's call it `Mothership`). Every day, I scan the CDC on the transactional databases to extract the changes, compute the delta forecast, and merge this `Delta` with the `Mothership`. Problem is, the performance is wildly inconsistent. `Mothership` has 25M rows, and `Delta` has 1 - 2M rows. I've seen performance ranging in 8 minutes to an hour for the merge.

The MERGE statement is pretty straight forward:

```
MERGE INTO Mothership AS tgt
    USING Delta AS src
    ON Mothership.Key1 = Delta.Key1 AND ... AND Mothership.Key4 = Delta.Key4
    WHEN MATCHED AND Mothership.UpdateDate < Delta.UpdateDate
         (UPDATE all data columns on Mothership)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
         (INSERT into Mothership)
```

I have PRIMARY KEY defined on Key1 to Key4 on each table, and the performance is still yucky. Is there a bug in MERGE with regards to performance?

Comment: Can you post the execution plan?

Answer (score 1):

There have been (and are) some bugs discovered around the MERGE statement. Dan Guzman has identified some situations where MERGE gets affected by a race condition, details here 
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx

and Aaron Bertrand has a list of issues in a post here 
http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/02/t-sql-queries/another-merge-bug